# Windows server 2003: Make parent folder non-deletable or renameable?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, permissions, file-permissions

Windows Server 2003 machine.  All users are administrators.

I have a folder c:\projects.  I'd like to make the folder non-deletable and non-renameable (even to administrators).  However, administrators should have full control over existing folders and files inside of this folder as well as any new files or folders created inside this folder or any subfolders.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I'm not talking about making it "impossible" for administrators to edit. It's fine if they want to take ownership.  I'm talking about preventing the folder from being changed accidentally in everyday use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. "Administrators" can always take ownership and change permissions on all filesystem objects.

I'm also not seeing the "Delete" permission applied to "This folder only" working properly (under Windows XP Pro SP3 and Windows Server 2003 SP2, at least) working as I'd expect / want them to work, either.

I think you're fighting a losing battle.

Comment: The server is only accessed by a handful of administrator level people who need complete access to the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're not worried about Administrators legitimately and intentionally changing permissions or ownership on subfolders and files, but only worried about the "accidental" deletion or renaming of the parent folder?

If so, then add (or modify) 2 ACE's on the parent folder for the Administrators group:

1. Administrators: Permissions = READ & EXECUTE; Apply onto = This folder only
2. Administrators: Permissions = FULL; Apply onto = Subfolders and files only

Comment: You're aware that this prevents "Administrators" from creating subfolders or files in the top-level folder, aren't you?

Comment: Hmm... my bad. I guess they probably will need to create new files and folders.